# Does DangerousAddRef keep the whole SafeHandle alive or just the handle?

Tags: c#, unmanaged, handle, cer

I am in the situation where I have a c# object containing an HGLOBAL and a List<Delegate>.  The HGLOBAL holds references to the delegates and the HGLOBAL is registered in unmanaged code as a callback (specifically, a vtbl-style interface).

I'm trying to not get bogged down in the details of the overall design (I'm already expecting some screaming from those that understand what I'm doing in the previous paragraph).  My question is currently one of lifetime management using functions I wish were documented differently.

I have converted the class holding the HGLOBAL and the List<Delegate> into a subclass of SafeHandle (because of CriticalFinalizerObject and because HGLOBAL is kinda a handle), and I do have the class that is instantiating this using [CER-style atomic transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330799/using-constrained-execute-regions) to inform C# when the unmanaged code stops expecting it to stick around.

Does calling DangerousAddRef effectively bump up a reference count for the entire SafeHandle object?  Will the List<Delegate> be included in this reference count?  Another way of asking this is whether DangerousAddRef is effectively constructing a [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) to the entire SafeHandle object, or whether it is doing so simply to the SafeHandle.handle member inside?

If it is not applying to the object as a whole then the List<Delegate> is likely to be collected early and cause access violations when unmanaged code tries to call into it.

If it is applying to the object as a whole then I have just created a block of reference-counted objects within a garbage-collected heap and [I had better be darned sure that I haven't created any reference loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448(v=vs.85).aspx).

I suspect it's the latter, but there are very few Google searches on this kinda stuff, and when the only symptoms you're dealing with are unmanaged access violations from the finalizer thread on process shutdown when no actual managed code is being ran then it starts to get difficult to see whether you're going in the right direction.